# Magento 2 changed .php file in core but nothing happens

Tags: magento2

I am doing some changes to make digits in units working. I changed

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml
```

In my test it works correct, but in live environment the change is not comming true.

Other changes in .php files are working correct

Comment: I think its related to caching or static-content deployment, please  try to re-deploy static-content   in production

Comment: Since your Live Env in PRODUCTION MODE , your changes wont reflect in storefront , so go to magento root folder and type below command                        php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you must not change core files and the possible reason behind your problem should be one of these:
1) Either it's overridden in any custom extension
2) Its overridden in any frontend theme

Feel free to ask if you find any issue

Comment: Thanks Manish, neither option 1 or 2 can cause the problem. It tested it by removing all of the custom apps. Could it be redis caching?

Comment: yes, it could be.. try after refreshing cache.

Comment: Refreshing magento cache i did, no effect. Flushdb in redis?

Comment: I had to do a static content deploy

Comment: ok great, but try to override the file somewhere rather than changing the core.

Comment: And please give a thumbs up if you found my answer useful

Comment: Yep! Step 2, going to work at that

Comment: sounds good!!!!